# Laravel give value to form model, from join table

Tags: php, laravel, join

i have code to get data and join two table like this:

```
 $loan = Loan::findOrFail( $id )
            ->join('customers', 'loans.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
            ->join('loans_detail','loans.id','=','loans_detail.loans_id')
            ->get();
            return view( 'loans.detail', compact( [ 'loan' ] ) );
```

then i return that data to:

```
{!! Form::model( $loan, [ 'method' => 'put' ] ) !!}
{!! Form::text( 'payment_type', null, [ 'class' => 'form-control'] ) !!}
```

but the data (payment_type) does not appear. However if i remove the join code, the data (payment_type) is appears.

there is some diverent result if i use dd() for database with join table or not using data table

with join table

```
Builder {#783 ▼
  #query: Builder {#782 ▶}
  #model: Loan {#779 ▶}
  #eagerLoad: []
  #localMacros: []
  #onDelete: null
  #passthru: array:12 [▶]
  #scopes: []
  #removedScopes: []
}
```

with out join table

```
Loan {#779 ▼
  #table: "loans"
  #guarded: []
  #connection: "pgsql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:9 [▶]
  #original: array:9 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findOrFail()` already executes the query, calling `join()` afterwards starts a new query.

Try this:

```
$loan = Loan::whereKey($id)
    ->join('customers', 'loans.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
    ->join('loans_detail','loans.id','=','loans_detail.loans_id')
    ->first();
```

BTW: You should use relationsships for this kind of query:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships